# help ! my VENV theming only applies when i source .bashrc but my git theming work tho

Tags: bashrc

```sh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then

  #151;151;26 FADED GREEN

  curve_top=$'\U256d'
  curve_bot=$'\U2570'
  hline=$'\U2500'
  vline=$'\U2502'
  arrow=$'\U25B6'


  logo_bg=$(tput setab 2)
  logo_fg=$(tput setaf 8)
  logo_sep_bg=$(tput setab 8)
  logo_sep_fg=$(tput setaf 2)

  base_bg=$(tput setab 8)
  base_fg=$(tput setaf 15)
  base_sep_fg=$(tput setaf 8)
  base_sep_bg=$(tput setab 7)

  git_fg=$(tput setaf 0)
  git_bg=$(tput setab 7)
  git_sep_fg=$(tput setaf 7)

  arrow_fg=$(tput setaf 7)

  a="\001$(tput setaf 7)\002"

  bold=$(tput bold)
    
  reset=$(tput sgr0)

  TM=$(date +" "%I:%M:%S" "%p" ")

      #section_separators = { left = '', right = '' },
      #component_separators = { left = '', right = '' }

  BACK=$((${#TM}+3))

  if test -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ; then
    VENV="$git_fg$git_bg $(basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV") $reset"
  else
    VENV=''  
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
    GITS='$git_fg$git_bg$(__git_ps1 " git  %s ")$reset'
  else
    GITS='' 
  fi
  

  PS1='\n'
  
  PS1+='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}'
  
  PS1+='$curve_top$hline'                                                    # curve1    
  
  PS1+='$logo_bg$logo_fg  $logo_sep_bg$logo_sep_fg$reset'            # logo
  
  PS1+='$bold$base_bg$base_fg   $(basename $(pwd)) $base_sep_bg$base_sep_fg$reset' # basename
  
  PS1+='$VENV'

  PS1+='$GITS$git_sep_fg$reset' # git
  
  PS1+='$(tput hpa $(tput cols))$(tput cub $BACK)$reset' # move right  
  
  PS1+='$git_sep_fg$base_sep_bg$base_sep_fg$bold$base_bg$base_fg \[\t\] $logo_sep_fg$bold$logo_bg$logo_fg   $reset' # time 
  
  PS1+='\n$curve_bot$hline$arrow '

  function PROMPT() {
    PS1+=''
  } 
  PROMPT_COMMAND=PROMPT
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some text, tell us what system you are running, tell us what is currently happening and what you want to have happening instead. You have just dumped 60 lines of code with no context, no question, nothing. We can't help you unless you explain what you need from us.